# Is there a CSS reset for typography that can be applied to a specific class?

Tags: css

Is there a reliable CSS typography boilerplate, which works under a namespace (i.e., a class) and not globally?

Let me briefly explain the situation: I'm using a CSS reset for layout and I'd like to be able to add a certain class (`.content` for example) to a `div`, which would then apply some uniform typography rules to that `div`'s elements only:

```
<p>This one's reset</p>
<div class="content">
    <p>This one has typography rules applied</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are "typography rules"?

Comment: This is the basics of css, add a class in front of your reset css and now it is namespaced. If you don't have a css preprocessor (which would make this very easy) then you will need to do some work to add the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, there is no such thing. And if you take a CSS typography boilerplate, you'll have to add a namespace yourself, which is an obvious solution, but not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> *which would then apply some uniform typography rules to that div's
>   elements only*

If I understand correctly, you would just do this in your stylesheet, if you wanted to target *every* element in that `div`

```
div.content *{
    /* YOUR STYLES */     
}
```

If you want to style just the `p`s in that `div` then

```
div.content p{
    /* YOUR STYLES */     
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8UE2D/

Comment: Good idea! You can even write `.content * {...}` without the div, so it works for all elements of and within this class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any pre-existing boiler plate. You'd just have to to a search and replace to to prepend .content to each selector in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is late, but there is such a thing, see: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-boilerplate-for-css-typography

The demo is here: http://files.www.gethifi.com/blog/a-boilerplate-for-css-typography/demo/type.html

It's a CSS boilerplate which sets sizing, margins, and line-height (basically things to line up elements along a common baseline).

According to the site,

> By default, all rules are preceeded with ".content".  This is to make it easy to apply this stylesheet to a particular container.

I haven't used it but did confirm that the typography.css file has the rules prepended with .content.

Answer (score -1):

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) will generate well tested @font-face syntax for you, and Paul Irish has the [Bulletproof @font-face technique](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) explanation so you can understand the thought process behind Font Squirrel.

Font Squirrel will end up giving you CSS similar to this:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'MyWebFont'; 
    src: url('WebFont.eot'); 
    src: url('WebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg'); 
}
```

Which you can include in your style sheet and then reference with a `.content` class like this:

```
.content { 
    font-family: 'WebFont', Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```